# jQuery .click stop all elements with the same class opening on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

I have written this function that binds to a button, which when clicked toggles the class to provide a dropdown. The only problem is is that I have multiple buttons on the same page that have the same functionality, and they all fire when one is clicked:

Any and all help greatly appricated :)

```js
app.bind.DirectionDropdown = function(){
    
  $('.direction-button').bind('click', function(){
        
    $('.direction-dropdown').toggleClass('active');
    
  });
  
};
```

```css
.fade-in {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s,opacity .3s ease-in-out,all .3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: visibility 0s,opacity .3s ease-in-out,all .3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: visibility 0s,opacity .3s ease-in-out,all .3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: visibility 0s,opacity .3s ease-in-out,all .3s ease-in-out;
}
.active {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(0,0);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0,0);
  -moz-transform: translate(0,0);
  -ms-transform: translate(0,0);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" title="#" class="direction-button">Click to reveal text</a>

<div class="direction-dropdown fade-in">
<p>Reveal this</p>
</div>

<a href="#" title="#" class="direction-button">Click to reveal text</a>

<div class="direction-dropdown fade-in">
<p>Reveal this</p>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `this` keyword, and target only the `.direction-dropdown` following the `.direction-button`

```
$('.direction-button').on('click', function(){

    $(this).next('.direction-dropdown').toggleClass('active');

});
```

Comment: This makes sense, but the event now fires and nothing happens? Is there anything else you would suggest?

Comment: @lucasjohnson - all I can do, is test it, and it seems to work just fine -> https://jsfiddle.net/21xj96up/

Comment: Yes, you are right. There must be a reason why it is not working in my file.

Answer (score 1):

In your callback you need to use this instead of .direction-button:

```
 $('.direction-button').bind('click', function(){

    $(this).toggleClass('active');

 });
```

$(".direction-button") makes JQuery search in the entire DOM object